# jboss-eap-6.1 oracle driver definition when installed as deployment

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, jboss

I have several Jboss EAP 6.1 installations working with Oracle driver installed as a module.

This is the standard configuration I use in standalone.xml:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/fooDatasource" pool-name="java:jboss/fooDatasource" enabled="true" use-java-context="false" >
 <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.2.3.4:1527/SOMEDB.foo</connection-url>
 <driver>oracle</driver>
     <security>
         <user-name>xxxxx</user-name>
             <password>xxxxxxxxx</password>
     </security>
 [...]
</datasource>
<driver name="oracle" module="oracle.jdbc">
    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</datasource-class>
</driver>
```

The ojdbc6.jar is in $JBOSS_HOME/modules/system/layers/base/oracle/jdbc/main/ together with the appropriate module.xml and everything works fine.

Now a customer required to install the driver as a deployment, so I moved ojdbc6.jar to $JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments/ and I see from logs that it is deployed without errors:

```
[org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver (version 11.2)
INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) JBAS018559: Deployed "ojdbc6.jar" (runtime-name : "ojdbc6.jar")
```

But I don't know how to edit my standalone.xml to make it work again: i tried to edit the driver definition "module" attribute with several different values (ojdbc6.jar, deployment.ojdbc6.jar, oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver...) but none seem to "match" and Jboss keeps throwing errors at startup:

```
ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 24) JBAS014613: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
("subsystem" => "datasources"),
("jdbc-driver" => "oracle")
]) - failure description: "JBAS010441: Failed to load module for driver [ojdbc6.jar]"
[...]
INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014774: Service status report
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
  service jboss.jdbc-driver.oracle (missing) dependents: [service jboss.driver-demander.java:jboss/spiDatasource, service jboss.data-source.java:jboss/fooDatasource]
```

Could anyone please provide a working example of the driver definition?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself.

Surprisingly, all the guides I found around explain how to do this configuration via web admin interface or via jboss-cli, but no one in the Jboss community seem to bother explaining how to manually edit the standalone.xml to do the job.

This is a working example (basically I just **deleted** the entire Oracle *driver* definition section and replaced the driver name in the *datasource* definition with the name of the runtime name of the deployed jar file):

```
<datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:/jdbc/fooDS" pool-name="foo-ds" use-ccm="false">
    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@1.2.3.4:1527/SOMEDB.foo</connection-url>
    <driver-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</driver-class>
    <driver>ojdbc6.jar</driver>

    [...] other datasource stuff here

</datasource>

# DELETE FROM HERE...
<driver name="oracle" module="oracle.jdbc">
    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</datasource-class>
</driver>
# ...TO HERE
```

That's all.

Answer (score -1):

**Probably you have to mention in this way...**

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.1">
        <datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/XXX" pool-name="XXX"     enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@SID:PORT:DBNAME</connection-url>
                <driver>oracle</driver>
                <security>
                    <user-name>user</user-name>
                    <password>password</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="oracle" module="com.oracle">
                    <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    <datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver</datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
</subsystem>
```

Comment: While this code block may answer the question, you always should provide some explanation for why it does so.

Answer (score -1):

1. Create directories like x1/x2/main
2. Create module.xml file under main directory
3. Keep ojdbc6-11.1.1.3.0.jar  in main directory level

In Module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="x1.x2">
<properties>
    <property name="jboss.api" value="unsupported"/>
</properties>
<resources>
    <resource-root path="ojdbc6-11.1.1.3.0.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
</dependencies>
```

In domain.xml

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:/TestName" pool-name="TestName" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:oracle:thin:@ldap://xxxxx:3000/UKXXX,cn=OracleContext,dc=dcm,dc=XXXX</connection-url>
                    <driver>dps</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>XXXXX</user-name>
                        <password>*****</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="dps" module="x1.x2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>
```

**Try to keep the correct ojdbc jar, some versions won't work :)**

Comment: I think you didn't read my question well... I already had a working module configuration. I asked how to get rid of that, and switch to a different one.  The question is already solved, by the way